# why does `timeout 2 timeout 1 bash` stuck

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timeout, signals

I am studying the `timeout` command in Linux shell.

When I try `timeout 1 bash`, bash will run and will be killed after 1 second.

When I try `timeout 2 timeout 1 yes`, the program `yes` will run for 1 second and be killed by the second `timeout`.

But when I try `timeout 2 timeout 1 bash`, it is stuck. No bash shell appears and it keep running even if I press Ctrl+C.

I know that it is not useful to write two `timeout` in one command.

I only wonder why this will happen.

Comment: Indeed interesting. I tried it with other shells (fish, zsh), and it worked. With bash, it works if you invoke the outer timeout with -k, i.e. `timeout -k 3 2 timeout 1 bash`. I don't know what bash is doing so special that the outer timeout command will be compromised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another example of the same behavior:

`strace timeout 1 bash` 
Even if you interrupt the strace, bash will continue running.

If we strace the bash process itself in the same time, we notice the following looping.

> --- SIGTTIN {si_signo=SIGTTIN, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=7162, si_uid=1000} --- rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN,
>   sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f097723a7e0},
>   {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER,
>   sa_restorer=0x7f097723a7e0}, 8) = 0 ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [6412])
>   = 0 rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f097723a7e0},
>   {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER,
>   sa_restorer=0x7f097723a7e0}, 8) = 0 kill(0, SIGTTIN)
>   = 0

Now, according to http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html

> Macro: int SIGTTIN
>
> A process cannot read from the user’s terminal while it is running as a background job. When any process in a background job tries to
>   read from the terminal, all of the processes in the job are sent a
>   SIGTTIN signal. The default action for this signal is to stop the
>   process. For more information about how this interacts with the
>   terminal driver, see Access to the Terminal.

`timeout 2 timeout --foreground 1 bash` works, because the inner timeout will allow it to work with the tty, although it is not run directly from the interactive shell.

*man timeout*

```
   --foreground

          when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,

          allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

We can chain as many timeouts as we want, as long as all but the one ran from the interactive shell are with the `--foreground` option:

`timeout 3 timeout --foreground 2  timeout --foreground 1 bash`

Also check the `SIGNALS` section in `man bash` for more info on how bash reacts to the various signals in different cases.